# How to get max version from different table and join the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to join Project table with table 2 and the issue i am facing is not with a join but in Table 2 there is Colum name Version so one project can have multiple version and i wanted to join project table and table 2 and i only wanted to get the data with Max version of project from Table 2. 
I tried to jointhe table 2 to project and applied MAX function which is giving me right information but the main issue id i also want ID column of Table 2 in the data but when i tried that i am getting error.

I tried to join Prject table and table 2 and applied MAX function in Select subquery. gave me right data but when i include to get one more column from table 2 which is id it gave me error.

ERRO"Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Column 'table2.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
"

```
SELECT
p.ProjectId,
p.ProjectName,
p.ProjectStatusId,
ps.Description AS ProjectStatusDescription,
ph.Description AS ProjectPhaseDescription,
   (Select MAX(t2.version), w.id from Table2 t2 join project on t2.id =  
    project.id group by t2.Projectid)

FROM 
Project p
JOIN ProjectStatus ps on p.ProjectStatusId = ps.ProjectStatusId
JOIN ProjectPhase ph on p.ProjectPhaseId = ph.ProjectPhaseId
where p.projectid = 32388
```

Project table Column - PRoject id , Project NAme , Project status
 table 2 column- id, verion 
 condition - i only want max version from table 2

Comment: What table `w.` alias stands for? And how it connected to the rest of the tables?

Comment: sorry it was mistake id is from table 2 it should be t2.id not w.id

Answer (score 0):

Joining to a subquery which aggregates the `Table2` table might be what you want here:

```
SELECT
    p.ProjectId,
    p.ProjectName,
    p.ProjectStatusId,
    ps.Description AS ProjectStatusDescription,
    ph.Description AS ProjectPhaseDescription,
    adfadf
FROM Project p
INNER JOIN ProjectStatus ps
    ON p.ProjectStatusId = ps.ProjectStatusId
INNER JOIN ProjectPhase ph
    ON p.ProjectPhaseId = ph.ProjectPhaseId
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Projectid, MAX(version) AS max_verison
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY Projectid
) t2
    ON t2.id = p.id     -- unsure of this join condition
WHERE
    p.projectid = 32388;
```

As I commented above, I'm not sure what the exact join condition should be.  You basically would want to connect the max subquery from `Projectid` in `Table2` to a column in the outer query which logically matches this.

Comment: Thank you very much. But can i ask one more question?

Comment: If i am trying to Attach ID column from Table to it is giving me multiple data . SELECT
    p.ProjectId,
    p.ProjectName,
    p.ProjectStatusId,
    ps.Description AS ProjectStatusDescription,
    ph.Description AS ProjectPhaseDescription,
 wa.ProjectId,
 wa.maxverison,
 w.id

Comment: SELECT
    p.ProjectId,
    p.ProjectName,
    p.ProjectStatusId,
    ps.Description AS ProjectStatusDescription,
    ph.Description AS ProjectPhaseDescription,
 wa.ProjectId,
 wa.maxverison,
 w.id

FROM Project p
INNER JOIN ProjectStatus ps
    ON p.ProjectStatusId = ps.ProjectStatusId
INNER JOIN ProjectPhase ph
    ON p.ProjectPhaseId = ph.ProjectPhaseId

Comment: INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(waversion) AS maxverison ,ProjectId
    FROM WorkAuthorization
    GROUP BY ProjectId
) wa
    ON wa.projectid = p.projectid  
INNER JOIN   
(
 Select  ID,ProjectId
 from WorkAuthorization
)w
 on w.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
WHERE
    p.projectid = 32388;